# ASP.NET WEB API 406 error:for POST request using Media format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to web api stuff:

I am getting an error

> 406: Not Acceptable

error message in asp.net web api rest service.

In my rest service I’m using media format for my customized XML output, to get customized output.

I’m registering my formatted media in `Global.asax` page.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear(); 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new mynewformat());
```

all my methods are post methods with typed object as parameter and parameters are accepts from body.

Whenever I try to test the service… Getting `406: Not acceptable` error message.
can anyone please help me ... what could be the reason for this....???

I did notice couple of interesting points here...

1. If I’m commenting below line then I’m getting `200 (OK)` status code (which is fine.)... but format is not applying to output.

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
   ```
2. If i'm removing parameters in my service method.. Then its working
   fine..

I request everyone.. Please guide me what could be the reason/work around/solution/fix..for this issue.

Note:I don't want accept parameters from URI so i made it to accept from frombody only.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your `mynewformat` code

Comment: here is the link for the sample:http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2012/04/20/asp-net-web-api-extending-content-negotiation-with-new-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more to implementing a custom format than just adding it to the configuration formatters.  It starts with having to change the media-type header to a new custom type of your choosing (like "application/myNewFormat") for all requests, for the client.  On the back end, you have to implement a new *MediaTypeFormatter* that can handle the serialization.  This involves a bit more of code.

A good example of this resides here, it can easily be stripped to boiler-plate code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We